# How to learn programming GPS applications in Android

Tags: android, gps

A few weeks ago, I began learning to write Android applications, that must use GPS (getting position and saving it to a database). But I found so much information; I don't know where to start!

**Question:**

Please help me make my studying comprehensive and complete!

What help was most useful for you (or most understandable) when you were learning this topic?
(Please provide links to useful topics or video lessons)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for useful book I can suggest you "Professional Android Sensor Programming" (G. Milette, A. Stroud).

I can also suggest this link:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

or a basic presentation:

http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/android-gps-tutorial

finally, I think you should always refer to developer.android.com web site:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html